# Why does the complexity of the particle filter scales exponentially with the number of dimentions?

Tags: mobile-robot, localization, particle-filter

In the [AI for Robotics course from Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/artificial-intelligence-for-robotics--cs373), Sebastian Thrun mentions that *"the complexity of the particle filter grows exponentially with the number of dimensions"*. Why is this the case? We have to keep track of $n$ particles each of which has $d$ dimensions so wouldn't the memory complexity be $O(n*d)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need enough particles so that you can sample across each of those dimensions.

If I have a particle filter with just `X` position, and my particles are spread in the range `[0, 1]`, I might need, e.g, 3 particles: `{0, 0.5, 1.0}`.

If I have a particle filter with `(X, Y)` position and both dimensions have  the same `[0, 1]` range, then I need one particle for every combination of `X` and `Y`: `{(0, 0), (0, 0.5), (0, 1), (0.5, 0), (0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 1), (1, 0), (1, 0.5), (1, 1)}`.

Answer (score 1):

It's the number of particles that will grow exponentially. An array of particles, with $n$ particles in each dimension, with $d$ dimensions, will have $n^d$ particles.